# R dplyr Add increasing number to columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a time series data, where I want to add an increasing number towards the left.
For example, at `V1` I want to add 1, at `V2` I want to add 2, so at `VN` the columns will receive an addition of +N.

As my mental model is fixated to dplyr like syntax, I really want to avoid loop operation if possible...

The idea is that I want to ensure the last column will receive the highest importance when I order/arrange these time series data. This can be done by getting the row by row summation later.

```
set.seed(1990)
ID <- rep(c('A','B','C'),each = 1)
n <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=45)
df <- tibble(ID)
df <- cbind(df, as.data.frame(matrix(n, nrow = 3)))
```

[image]

As of now, the table I have is not sorted properly as the time series has many gaps here and there.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make the df long with `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package - which belongs to the `tidyverse` - , add a dummy row which contains the number to be added, perform the addition, remove the dummy row and bring it back to the wider form.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1990)
ID <- rep(c('A','B','C'),each = 1)
n <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=45)
df <- tibble(ID)
df <- cbind(df, as.data.frame(matrix(n, nrow = 3)))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(V1:V15) %>% 
  mutate(rn = rep(1:15,3)) %>% 
  mutate(value = value + rn) %>% 
  select(-rn) %>% 
  pivot_wider()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 16
#>   ID       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A         1     3     3     4     6     6     8     8     9    11    12    12
#> 2 B         1     3     4     5     5     6     8     8     9    10    11    12
#> 3 C         2     3     3     5     6     7     8     8     9    10    12    12
#> # … with 3 more variables: V13 <dbl>, V14 <dbl>, V15 <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks @MarBlo, I ended up using this variation because Power BI service dplyr version is still not as up to date which means some later features of dplyr like `across` is not useable. Also your answer gives me more flexibility to add conditions within the `mutate` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of base R options using 1) `Map` and 2) `sweep`

```
#1)
df[-1] <- Map(`+`, df[-1], seq_along(df[-1]))

#2)
df[-1] <- sweep(df[-1], 2, seq_along(df[-1]), `+`)
```

Using the latest `dplyr` (>=1.0.0) you can use `cur_column()` in the following way :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(V1:V15, ~. + match(cur_column(), names(df)) - 1))
```

Or using `purrr`'s `map2` similar to base R approach :

```
df[-1] <- purrr::map2(df[-1], seq_along(df[-1]), `+`)
```

All of which return :

```
df
#  ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
#1  A  1  3  3  4  6  6  8  8  9  11  12  12  13  15  16
#2  B  1  3  4  5  5  6  8  8  9  10  11  12  14  14  15
#3  C  2  3  3  5  6  7  8  8  9  10  12  12  14  15  16
```

Comment: I like the `sweep` option. What about one just adding a matrix to the df?

Comment: Do you mean repeating the values to make `df` and values to add of same length so that we can directly add them?

Comment: Indeedly, some variation like that.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, I choose this answer because it captures the dplyr syntax and I also learn about new feature like `across`. However I'm pushing my R visual to Power BI, and unfortunately Power BI Service is still not up to date which means `across` is not supported. The other variations you gave  are supported of course.